# How to process 3d gaussian convolution with a 3d array or matrix in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, multidimensional-array, convolution

I have a 3d array like this.

```
int sz[] = {240, 240, 240};
Mat accumarray(3, sz, CV_32S, Scalar::all(0)) ;
```

And I want to process a 3d gaussian convolution on this array to blur the array. To make data in the array somehow be continuous.

However OpenCV only has 1d or 2d dft(), filter2d(), convolve().

Then how to process a 3d convolution in OpenCV? 
and how to build a 3d gaussian kernel efficiently? 
and how to separate the 3d convolution into multiple 2d or 1d convolution?

Comment: It sounds like you've chosen the wrong wrench to pound in the screw. Things like convolution operators have a mathematical/physical meaning. The reason graphics libraries wouldn't implement these on a 3D grid is that they correspond to physical operations that generally aren't visible to people who can only see things in 3 dimensional space. Could you give a bit more background as to what you're trying to do?

Comment: for example, I have an accumulate array, 0 0 0 5 0 0 0, and I want to blur it, to such 0 1 1 1 1 1 0. My problem is such in 3d case. the data is discrete in the 3d array, I want them to be continuous. To setup a Lab Skin Chroma model with openCV